# How to figure out whether DNS is propagating or not?

Tags: dns

I'm at wits end. I have a WordPress site that will be advertised in a major newspaper in a few hours. I tried setting it up with Cloudflare in anticipation of the traffic but it wasn't working so I turned cloudflare off and reset back the dns setting back to my original DNS servers. It's been about 2 hours and the site is still not coming up for me on my ISP. How can I tell how widespread this problem is? I have tried various online tools but I am getting mixed results and I'm not sure how to interpret them and I'm not sure if the site is resolving. I removed the site totally from Cloudflare. I would think it would have propagated by now and so I'm getting really nervous that something is wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the real domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do NOT make repetitive DNS actions especially changing dns servers. any way to check propagation this tool is good enough https://dnschecker.org/ and on if you try on your own machine always use incognito or private browsing and clear your DNS chace `ipconfig /flush dns`
for the cloudflare you have to add all dns entries, change name servers on registrar panel and wait for propagation.